# con SHELL (linux), cuál programa muestra archivo de texto y las líneas "larguisimas" las finaliza con "..."?

Tags: linux, shell

en CentOS,
necesito abrir archivos de configuración utilizando SHELL,
y ver la línea "RECORTADA" cuando séa my larga, (overflow=HIDDEN).

no lo he logrado con **cat /archivo.conf**

con qué programa puedo hacerlo?

hay alguno que me permita ver "..." al final de cáda línea que tenga overflow ?

(sí, ocultar el overflow de cáda línea, como lo háce VisualStudio y otros editores)

gracias!

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `nano`?

Comment: gracias, **nano** me abre para editar, yo solo quiero visualizar

Answer (score 1):

### Usando [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

```
awk -v cols=79 '{print (length($0) > cols) ? substr($0, 0, cols - 3) "..." : $0}' archivo.conf
```

- `-v cols=79` establece una variable awk llamada `cols` que especifica el máximo de caracteres por linea.
- `(length($0) > columns)` es la condición del operador ternario, comprueba si la linea tiene mas de los caracteres estipulados. `$0` hace referencia a la linea actual.
- Si se cumple la condición se imprime una subcadena de la linea cortando los caracteres sobrantes y agregando "...".
- Si no se cumple se imprime la linea sin mas.

También puedes hacer uso de la variable SHELL `$COLUMNS`, de forma que se adapte al tamaño de la consola:

```
awk -v cols=$COLUMNS '{print (length($0) > cols) ? substr($0, 0, cols - 3) "..." : $0}' archivo.conf
```

### Usando [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)

Con [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) y su comando `s` se podría conseguir también, el uso de la expresión regular quizás no lo haga muy legible, pero algo como:

```
sed "s/\(.\{79\}\).*/\1.../" archivo.conf
```

o:

```
sed "s/\(.\{$((COLUMNS-3))\}\).*/\1.../" archivo.conf
```

### Usando [`less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) / [`most`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/most)

Otra opción seria usar `less` con `-S` / `--chop-long-lines`, si no te es muy importante que muestre `>` en vez de "...":

```
less -S archivo.conf
```

La principal ventaja es que **en vez de truncar y eliminar el texto de las lineas largas como las opciones anteriores, `less -S` desactiva el ajuste de linea permitiéndote desplazarte de derecha a izquierda para visualizar todo el documento, como si simulara un scroll**. Pulsando la tecla flecha derecha del teclado puedes hacer que se desplace hacia la derecha mostrando el contenido cortado (con la flecha izquierda desplaza hacia la izquierda de nuevo, `q` para salir).

Como evolución de `less`, existe también `most`, aunque es menos común que venga instalado por defecto:

```
most archivo.conf
```

### Desactivar el ajuste de linea en la terminal

Una opción es desactivar el ajustado de lineas a nivel de la terminal directamente. Por ejemplo, con:

```
setterm -linewrap off
```

tras el cual puedes usar `cat` y las lineas serán truncadas en vez de ajustarse. No obstante, esto depende de la terminal de turno y de sus capacidades.

---

Existen seguro muchas mas opciones, por ejemplo, se podrían conseguir algunos resultados con `cat` + `cut`:

```
cat archivo.conf | cut -c1-79
```

pero `cut` tiene algunos inconvenientes, por ejemplo si tienes caracteres multibyte puede cortar por donde no debe y terminar con cosas como:

```
ññññññññññññññññññ� <<< caracter ñ mutilado...
```

O simplemente usar `nano` pero con la opción `-v` (`--view`) para desactivar la edición:

```
nano archivo.conf -v
```

Comment: gracias maestro ***@FJSevilla***, (carambas!!, medallas 7, 39, 61 :-O !!!) ésta línea me ha trabajado muy bien (la cambié a 99): `awk -v cols=99 '{print (length($0) > cols) ? substr($0, 0, cols - 3) "..." : $0}' /A` ésta es MUY buena: `less -S /etc/csf/A` ésta se lléva 10 de 10, es PERFECTA para mís necesidades: `sed "s/\(.\{$((COLUMNS-3))\}\).*/\1.../" /etc/csf/A` ningún parametro en **cat** lo permitiría?

Answer (score 0):

Mala idea, pero también funciona usando python de esta manera:

```py
import sys
i = 1
limit = 4
etc_string = '...'
for row in sys.stdin.readlines():
    for l in row:
        if i <= limit:
            print(l, end='')
        elif i > limit:
            print(etc_string, end='')
            break
        i = i+1
    print()
    i = 1
```

Por ejemplo:

```bash
head -n 10 /etc/passwd | python -c "import sys
i = 1
limit = 4
etc_string = '...'
for row in sys.stdin.readlines():
    for l in row:
        if i <= limit:
            print(l, end='')
        elif i > limit:
            print(etc_string, end='')
            break
        i = i+1
    print()
    i = 1
"
```

Y de esa manera puedes hacer un programa exclusivo e innecesario para tu tarea:

Contenido de elipsis.py:

```py
import sys

limit = int(sys.argv[1])
etc_string = sys.argv[2]

i = 1
for row in sys.stdin.readlines():
    for l in row:
        if i > limit:
            print(etc_string)
            break
        print(l, end='')
        i = i+1
    i = 1
```

Y lo corres de la sig forma:

```bash
$ head -n 10 /etc/passwd | python elipsis.py 4 '***'
root***
daem***
bin:***
sys:***
sync***
game***
man:***
lp:x***
mail***
news***
```

Comment: @XHtml Si te funcionó alguna de las respuestas dadas, vota positivamente a todas las que creas que contribuyen. Si usaste alguna y esa fue la que resolvió tu problema, vota positivamente en señal de agradecimiento y para que otras personas con tu misma duda puedan ir facilmente a la pregunta más aceptada. Osea, no seas un csmr

Comment: gracias **@Cuauhtli** las repuestas del maestro **@FJSevilla** han sído 100% útiles, al minuto de **él** publicarlas intenté DARLES UN VOTO POSITIVO, pero la plataforma no me lo permite. :'(

Comment: Entonces StackOverflow es el csmr